# Grails default root path

Tags: grails

Is there a variable where we can find out the root directory of my Grails application?

I tried request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
But shows tmp/App-Test-0.1/ .

My app is located in tomcat "/home/srinath/work/projects/tomcat-6.0.18/webapps/App-Test-0.1"

could any one help me .

thanks in advance,
sri..

Answer (score 2):

MainContext:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder;
ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext)ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext();
```

Example:

```
ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext().getResource("/").getFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the following call on grailsApplication bean

```
 grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath('')
```